# TemplateDoesNotExist even if the path set is correct

Tags: django, html, django-templates

[Look and help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO974.png)
I think the path entered in the code is correct,still it's showing template doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Django looks for templates inside`templates` folder but it is recommended to have sub folder with **Appname** inside your templates folder where your html should resides.

so change the name of folder `Snippet` to `customer` and then your link should be:

```
{%include 'customer/shop_card.html' with instance=shop %}
```

or try:

```
{%include 'shop_card.html' with instance=shop %}
```

Comment: Did you change the folder structure as mentioned in **answer ?**

Answer (score 0):

This would be the answer    :-

```
            {% include 'snippets/shop_card.html' with instance=shop %}
```

The default folder for searching the templates is "template/templates"
So you don't have to give extra details about the path.
If you only write

```
{% include 'shop_card.html' with instance=shop %}
```

it will search inside the folder templates,which doesn;t have that file.

If you have any folder inside "template/templates" specify the name of that folder and file inside it, in this case it's 'snippets/shop_card.html'.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: This absolutely cleared the concept and also worked.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Django looks for template by following the "TEMPLATES" setting. If not specified and "TEMPLATES" -> "APP_DIRS" in settings is True, Django will look into "templates" folder in each apps (and by default, templates need to be in folder "app/templates/{app_name}" which as ans2human said).

So better to set the TEMPLATES -> 'DIRS' in settings.py if you plan to put them in none-default places. e.g.

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'customers', 'templates'),
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'other', 'place', 'templates'),
    ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

Comment: settings are correct.
look @Change Sierra Jonathan answer,it helped me

Comment: That's great. I answered same time so that not seen it's already solved.